# "Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\FormExtension::$renderer" property is deprecated

Tags: php, symfony, twig, twig-extension, symfony-3.2

I upgraded from Symfony 3.1 to 3.2.

When running my PHPUnit tests, I get :

> Using the "Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\FormExtension::$renderer" property is deprecated since version 3.2 as it will be removed in 4.0

I'm not sure what to do.

Can you help ?

Regards

Comment: I know what deprecated is. But I dont use explicitely the FormExtension mentionned there. And dont really get where to look.

Comment: The Upgrade-3.2.md mentions the renderer in TwigBridge though I don't see how it is applicable unless maybe you did not update twig itself?

Comment: @bc004346 I don't have `renderer` property in my code

Comment: @Cerad Twig and Twig Extension seems to be up to date (v2.3.0 and  v1.4.1)

Comment: Are you by any chance using any unusual 3rd party bundles?  Might try bringing down a fresh 3.2 project and seeing if you get the same notice.  Of course you really don't have to do anything.  Your code should continue to work just fine at least until S4 comes along.